# How to install GTK in Windows for PHP?

Tags: php, windows, gtk

I am looking for PHP build apps using PHP. And I know that PHP is server-side language that runs in server not client.

While googling I came across GTK. As far as I know GTK is tool to build desktop application with PHP (please correct me if I am wrong). So I decided to give it a try. The link is here [Version to choose](http://gtk.php.net/download.php?language=en-US). I downloaded PHP-GTK-2.0.1 Source. Now I don't know how to install this to my Windows 7.

Unzip the file `master.zip`.

```
cd php-gtk-src-master
./buildconf
./configure
make
make install
```

I successfully executed `buildconf.bat` and `configure.bat`. But there is no make file or `make.bat` file. So I am stuck on this part.

How to install GTK for PHP in Windows7?

Comment: Surely `make` refers to [the Make program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software)), not a `.bat` file? Also, PHP and GTK to build applications for Windows sounds like two really bad choices.

Comment: thanks for replay. can you tell me what app i should use insteade of grk for client side desktop?

Comment: Do yourself a huge favour and pick a language and sdk more suitable for the task in hand - php is specifically designed as a stateless server side language, not at all suitable for thick client (state-full) apps. If you want to develop for windows specifically, download a (free) copy of visual studio and learn some c# (or vb, f#) and winforms (or wpf).

Comment: Thanks for your replay. I think I should stick with browser.

Comment: @Omkar For what it's worth GTK+ is tool to build desktop application with *any language*, not just PHP, and that while there are PHP programs that run on the client, it's not incredibly common. That being said, you could have gone with the binary links on that page as well; those will give you precompiled GTK+. You would still need to figure out how to install it, but you won't need to compile it.

Comment: @Steve I am not a big fan of PHP but surely it is not "specifically designed as a stateless server side language": one of the most successful application in PHP I know of (composer) is a client program.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you know you have much better options, in the link you provided you can download the *PHP-GTK-2.0.1 binary pack*: it includes everything you need on windows without requiring to build everything.

Read the `README.txt` included in the archive for hints on how to start.

Answer (score 0):

ther is a package for PHP5 and Gtk2.
without build to do.
just unzip it in a folder:(mine is C:\php-gtk) for exemple.
just set the php.exe path in your Path environment variable.
look in the php.ini to set the correct ext path to your installation (C:\php-gtk\ext). And it's ready.
there is a demo folder for testing. 
Bye.